# MySQL database table creation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In a MySQL database, a table has been created  as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub` (
`s_id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Standard id',
`std` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Standard',
`sub_nm` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Subject Name',
 PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`),
 KEY `sub_nm` (`sub_nm`),
 KEY `sub_nm_2` (`sub_nm`),
 KEY `sub_nm_3` (`sub_nm`)
 )    ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='All Subjects with
     corresponding standerds.' AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

My question is, what is meant by the last three KEY values? I mean:   KEY `sub_nm` (`sub_nm`), KEY `sub_nm_2` (`sub_nm`), and  KEY `sub_nm_3` (`sub_nm`)

Answer (score 1):

> KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

[For more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 1):

With this instruction 
    KEY `sub_nm` (`sub_nm`),
    KEY `sub_nm_2` (`sub_nm`),
    KEY `sub_nm_3` (`sub_nm`)
you create 3 indexes for sub_nm column named sun_nm, sub_nm_2 and  sub_nm_3

Comment: what is the benefit of multiple index? @Taras Soroka

Comment: General, with multiple indexes (for example ... KEY ind1 (column_1), KEY ind2 (column2), ..... ) you can index combinations of column values and speed up queries such as 
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE column1=X AND column_2=Y
but in your case I really do not know what is mean of creating 3 indexes for 1 field.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have already addressed your question that `KEY` and `INDEX` keywords are synonymous. In addition to that, here are a couple of examples.

**Create an index by using `INDEX` or `KEY` keyword during table creation**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub` (
  `s_id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Standard id',
  `std` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Standard',
  `sub_nm` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Subject Name',
   PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`),
   INDEX `sub_nm` (`sub_nm`),
   INDEX `sub_nm_2` (`sub_nm`),
   INDEX `sub_nm_3` (`sub_nm`)
 );
```

It is not wise to create 3 indexes on the same field. One index is enough on `sub_nm`.

**Create an index after table creation**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub` (
  `s_id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Standard id',
  `std` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Standard',
  `sub_nm` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Subject Name',
   PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`)
 );

 create index sub_nm on `sub`(sub_nm);
 -- create key sub_nm2 on `sub`(sub_nm); WILL ERROR OUT
 alter table `sub` add index sub_nm3 (sub_nm); 
 alter table `sub` add key sub_nm4 (sub_nm);
```

Notice the different ways one can create index on the table. I generally use index name like this: idx_tablename_fieldname (e.g. idx_sub_sub_nm).

Index on sub_nm may improve performance of queries that utilize sub_nm in filtering, sorting and grouping. `EXPLAIN` helps in identifying if the database believes an index will be used. If database doesn't use a query that you very strongly believe it should, [index hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html) can be provided in the query like this:

```
select s_id from sub use index (idx_sub_sub_nm) where sub_nm = 'test';
```